# How to transfer your Overwatch friends' list to the PTR?

Tags: overwatch, battle.net

I have a list of friends, most of whom I've added using the 'recent players' feature in the main Overwatch game.

I'm attempting to add these people on the PTR (because my friends' list doesn't sync, I guess) but I don't have their full battletag.

Is there any way to either see their battletags or sync the friends list?

Answer (score 2):

You can't sync friends lists from live.

PTR uses a completely different friends list than the live server does.

From the main BattleNet client, you can see a person's Friend ID by highlighting over their name in the Friends list.

Comment: ...and before you ask, no I couldn't tell you why Blizzard made that choice.

Comment: On a side note, the current PTR import is from before the Halloween event.